# Trying to capture Client IP Address for already running server in localhost, but node.js conflicts with existing server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to capture client ipaddress for traffic visiting my localhost:8080. I am using the following modules and the node.js application looks like this

```js
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var app = connect();

// require request-ip and register it as middleware
var requestIp = require('request-ip');

// you can override which attirbute the ip will be set on by
// passing in an options object with an attributeName
app.use(requestIp.mw({ attributeName : 'myCustomAttributeName' }))

// respond to all requests
app.use(function(req, res) {

    // use our custom attributeName that we registered in the middleware
    var ip = req.myCustomAttributeName;
    console.log(ip);
        
    fs.appendFile('iplist.csv', ip, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Some error occured - file either not saved or corrupted file saved');
        } else{
            console.log('It\'s saved!');
        }
    });

    // https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_isip_input
//     var ipType = net.isIP(ip); // returns 0 for invalid, 4 for IPv4, and 6 for IPv6
//     res.end('IP address is ' + ip + ' and is of type IPv' + ipType + '\n');
});

//create node.js http server and listen on port
app.listen(8080);
```

Is there any way I can listen to the already existing server without creating my own, hence avoiding the conflict of two servers fighting for the same port. I am new to node.js. Any help will be great. Thank you!

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: you have an existing server running on port 8080, and you want to log the IP-addresses of the clients that access that server? If so, you should (if possible) enable/add logging in that server, or otherwise use an external program like `tcpdump` to track and log incoming connections.

Comment: @robertklep What you have understood is exactly my situation, I will try to work with tcpdump and will get back with a situation update! Thank you